# receive multiple data over uart and storing these into a single buffer

Tags: c

I'm still little new to c and now im little confused over storing data onto a buffer

So let me first explain what I have achieved till now and what I want to achieve next

**Achieved**

Im able to continuously read the data from an sensor(lets say) store in a buffer and send data serially over the wirepas.

**To do**

I know that wirepas has 102bytes storage buffer it can allow
What i want to do is that store the sensor data in a continuous buffer and send that complete data at once so that im using the complete bandwidth of wirepas

lets say my each sensor data packet length is 27 bytes, so i can almost send 3 complete data in a single buffer and futher send over wirepas

Now want to know how to combine and store the data in an single buffer so i will utilize the complete buffer.

Comment: Unless there's extra data you haven't mentioned, you can easily send 3 packets in a single message.

Comment: What stops you from using a buffer with 3*27 bytes to collect sensor data?

Comment: I already getting data in an different buffer every time via uart ( storing uart data in an buffer), now how do I pass or create an new buffer that will wait for buffer to fill and then push the complete data to the gateway?